# Applied templates fails to match rule with multiple predicates

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

I have been trying to copy a node and alter its attributes. Basically, I want `<parent id="1">` to also have a `<child id="3">` and add an attribute to it, in this document:

```
 <container>
  <parent id="1">
    <child id="1"/>
    <child id="2"/>
  </parent>
  <parent id="2">
    <child id="1"/>
    <child id="2"/>
    <child id="3" attrs="I am special"/>
  </parent>
</container>
```

The resulting document would look like this:

```
 <container>
  <parent id="1">
    <child id="1"/>
    <child id="2"/>
    <child id="3" attrs="I am special" cloned="I have been cloned"/>
  </parent>
  <parent id="2">
    <child id="1"/>
    <child id="2"/>
    <child id="3" attrs="I am special"/>
  </parent>
</container>
```

To copy the child, I simply select the `parent` I want to populate and `apply-templates` with the object of his desire, likewise:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <!-- copy everything verbatim -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="identity">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="parent[@id='1']/child[last()]">
    <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//*/child[@id='3']"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With the copy taken care of, I have been trying to alter the attribute, but to no avail. Nothing is ever matched, and the attribute isn't added with the following template:

```
<xsl:template match="child[@id='3' and ../@id='1']">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
  <xsl:attribute name="clone">I have been cloned</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

With my limited understanding of XSLT, this would have been triggered during the `apply-templates`, would have have copied the nodes and added my attribute. The output says otherwise: `child id="3"` gets copied, but no sign of the attribute.

I was thinking perhaps the newly added node wasn't "accessible" yet, or something like that, but a simple rule will match it (this is not good because that modifies the original node I am copying from):

```
<xsl:template match="child[@id='3']">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    <xsl:attribute name="att1">I have been cloned?!</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

I thought I might have been was messing up the predicate, but adding an attribute with a similar predicate (minus the previous copy) works like a charm:

```
  <xsl:template match="child[@id='1' and ../@id='1']">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:attribute name="clone">Nope, just a normal kid</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

I also thought my "copy" template might have been matching with higher priority, but playing with priority didn't help either.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

The new element is part of the result tree, you can't match on it in the same transformation step. I would suggest to use a mode to alter the processing of the element to be added:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()" mode="#all">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="#current"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="parent[@id='1']/child[last()]">
    <xsl:next-match/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//*/child[@id='3']" mode="add-att"/>
  </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="child[@id='3']" mode="add-att">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
    <xsl:attribute name="att1">I have been cloned?!</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

Online at http://xsltransform.net/ncntCTd.